# Where/How does CiviCRM track sent reminder notices?

Tags: scheduled-reminders

CiviCRM can send reminders for memberships, activities, etc.  I noticed that if I create an activity and send a reminder email (by forcing the scheduled job to run) that the activity won't generate another email even if the parameters (within 0 hours of completion) are still valid.

Where/How does CiviCRM track a sent reminder so it doesn't send another?

Answer (score 5):

Info on sent reminders is stored in civicrm_action_log table.

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15728 may help you understand how it works.

Answer (score 2):

While this may be an obstacle for you right now, the fact that the scheduled reminders system doesn't send out reminders after the first one is definitely a good thing.  If you have the job for sending scheduled reminders set to hourly (my preferred method, since it avoids the possibility that reminders only ever go out late at night, making them unreliable for reminding someone about something tomorrow), you don't want everyone to get a reminder every hour.

If you want to remind someone multiple times per activity, you have two options:

- If you want the same message to go out, and the interval should be the same (every couple of days or something), enable repetition.
- If you want to vary the message or have a custom schedule (one month out, one week out, and then one day before, for example), just set up multiple reminders.  The system limits the reminders to once *per reminder* so other reminders set for the same activity won't interfere with each other.

Comment: Its a good thing - I agree!  Its also not explicit in the documentation that this is what happens, so I like to look in the database to understand how its preventing a send (and deleting the action_log entry makes testing iterations easier).