# Enabling membership reminders - will it only mail expirations valid this day?

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders

On a newly imported database, I am about to enable membership reminders. The first reminder is set to two months before expiration.

Can someone reassure me this mail will not get send to members that have *passed* the two months date, and are now eg 1 month before expiration ? And in particular, that it doesnt get send out to expired members ?

I guess I am asking - how does 'send_reminder' work ? Does it mail out on one particular day, or does it mark members to be mailed because they pass a treshold, and unmark them when done ? Because in the latter case, members that are due to expire in one month *would* receive the 2 month notice too, which is bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice would be to test this carefully in a test environment with the setting 'Outbound Email' set to 'redirect to database'. This means emails do not actually get sent, but you can see them in the database, and so also in the contact summary. That would be the best way to reassure you. Whatever someone says here about the core CiviCRM functionality, it will not show you what will happen in your specific installation and configuration. So I would always strongly recommend a local test.

Comment: and the 'official' documentation is here http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/membership/renewals/. My guess is that it will mail only once unless the members do not sign up again? So it will mail whoever is not renewed at a certain point in time

Comment: did this, but had outbound email written to a log. from playing around i found, on my dev installation (...), it mails the 2 months reminder exactly to the date - today is 12/06, it did not mail members expiring at 11/08 or 13/08, only the member expiring at 12/08. it never mailed him twice, not even after changing dates on both ends and rerunning the scheduled job.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing Erik, test it to be sure your configuration does what you want it to (there are at lot of variables in play... hard to say exactly what it will do).  Note that Civi has an internal record for whether or not a reminder has been sent, so if you do your testing on a live server it may not send that particular reminder again.  So use a test server, set the email to "redirect to database" and see what happens.

Also see [Where/How does CiviCRM track sent reminder notices?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/2374/142)