# Is there a way to see the results of Scheduled Reminders?

Tags: civimail, scheduled-reminders

A report? A log? I'd like to verify what it's doing in there...

Question answered: Activities Report can be filtered to "scheduled reminders" and show the results of automatic emails.

Comment: This questions is answered here: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/where-how-does-civicrm-track-sent-reminder-notices